# TastyPie - Override_urls ignores Authentication and Authorization

Tags: django, api, url, tastypie

I have the following resource:

```
class MyUserResource(resources.MongoEngineResource):

    class Meta:
        ...
        authentication = MyKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = ApiKeyAuthorization()

    def override_urls(self):
        return [...]
```

All API calls which are standard-tastypie are routed through the authentification and authorization. **But all customized functions/urls (which are in my override_urls) simply ignore the auth/auth functions...**

Any ideas why?

Edit:

Maybe the problem is that the dispatcher isn't called. The question remains why that is... and how I can change this behavior!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, finally I found out that when customizing / overriding my urls I also override the standard behavior of calling `wrap_view`. This causes the not-calling of `dispatch` which is in charge of checking the `auth`-methods.

So I just put the `auth`-checks manually in evey of my functions (like this):

```
self.is_authenticated(request)
self.is_authorized(request)
```

Hope this helps other desperate tastypie-developers :)

Comment: ``is_authorized`` function does not exists anymore, people interested in this question should check how the dispatch function works here : https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L470 and adapt the process to their needs.

Comment: adding `self.throttle_check(request); self.method_check(request, allowed=["post"])` at the start and `self.log_throttled_access(request)` at the end of the method might make it complete